# Passing data from a two-dimensional array to a structure

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct words {
  char *mas;
}words;

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt", "r");
  char str[100];
  char arr[100][100];
  int k=0;
  words_in->mas=malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof(arr));
  char *istr;
  printf("\nFile text\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        istr = fgets(str, 100, fp);
        printf("%s", istr);
        for (char* istr = strtok(str, " .\t\n"); istr; istr = strtok(NULL, " .\t\n")) {
            strcpy(arr[k++], istr);
        }
    }
```

How do I pass all words written to the two-dimensional array to the structure?

I want my structure to have an array of `char` pointers, instead of just one pointer. Or a linked list of pointers. Or an array of `struct`s.

And is it possible to somehow dynamically allocate memory for the structure and for arrays?

Comment: Well... yes. Only because arrays are sequential in memory as compared to an object created from `char**` If you have a 2D array (an array of 1D character arrays), then its size in memory is `rows * columns` bytes. You can allocate that amount for `mas` and then `memcpy` from the 2D array to `structinst.mas`. Your issue will next be that the strings in `structinst.mas` will begin on 100-char boundaries instead of one after the other. If you handle the offset in `.mas` correctly, there isn't any reason you can't do it this way.

Comment: To me it's unclear what you are asking for. The simple answer is : `memcpy(words_in->mas, &arr[0][0], sizeof(arr))` but I have a filling that it's not what you are looking for...

Comment: Ok, I went through the text from the file, and put all the words that met into the array "arr". And now I want to pass all the words from this 2D array to the structure "words"

Comment: That doesn't really make sense as the struct is just a single chat-pointer. Maybe you want it to be an array of char pointers!? Or a linked list or an array of structs?

Comment: Yes, that I want, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent two loops and you are ready to sacrifice some memory you can follow this approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct words {
  char **mas;
}words;

int main()
{
    FILE *fp=fopen("test.txt", "r");

    struct stat statbuf;
    fstat(fileno(fp), &statbuf);

    long f_size = statbuf.st_size;

    words words_in;
    words_in.mas = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * f_size); // In worst case each byte is one word.

    char fbuf[f_size+1];    // In worst case all bytes form one word ;

    long word_count = 0;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%s", fbuf) == 1) {
        words_in.mas[word_count] = strdup(fbuf);
        word_count++;
    }

    for (long i = 0; i < word_count; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",words_in.mas[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

INPUT 1

```
Apple
Bat
Cat
```

OUTPUT 1

```
Apple
Bat
Cat
```

INPUT 2

```
AppleBatCat
```

OUTPUT 2

```
AppleBatCat
```

INPUT 3

```
Apple Bat Cat
```

OUTPUT 3

```
Apple
Bat
Cat
```

Comment: `word_count` really belongs in the `struct`, not outside. Putting it inside also provides justification for the `struct` to exist.

Comment: Yes, I perfectly agree with you, when this struct is passed to any functions ``word_count`` is an important variable (if we dont mandate NULL  termination of char**). But, I dont want to deviate too much from the data structures created by OP.